# Counting occurences in an array and sorting in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array returned by the function `Search.all` :

```
=> [#<Search id: 7, name: "ap", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-16 00:58:42", updated_at: "2012-03-16 00:58:42">, #<Search id: 8, name: "papier", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-16 01:14:32", updated_at: "2012-03-16 01:14:32">, #<Search id: 9, name: "carton de jus", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-20 22:28:53", updated_at: "2012-03-20 22:28:53">, #<Search id: 10, name: "carton de jus", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-20 22:29:01", updated_at: "2012-03-20 22:29:01">, #<Search id: 11, name: "Papier", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-22 20:43:36", updated_at: "2012-03-22 20:43:36">, #<Search id: 12, name: "Papier", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-22 20:43:47", updated_at: "2012-03-22 20:43:47">, #<Search id: 13, name: "Salut", presence: false, created_at: "2012-03-24 20:34:49", updated_at: "2012-03-24 20:34:49">, #<Search id: 14, name: "carton", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:03", updated_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:03">, #<Search id: 15, name: "carton", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:11", updated_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:11">, #<Search id: 16, name: "carton", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:15", updated_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:15">, #<Search id: 17, name: "cellulaire", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:28", updated_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:28">, #<Search id: 18, name: "cellulaire", presence: true, created_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:36", updated_at: "2012-03-26 19:32:36">, #<Search id: 19, name: "montre", presence: false, created_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:26", updated_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:26">, #<Search id: 20, name: "montre", presence: false, created_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:29", updated_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:29">, #<Search id: 21, name: "montres", presence: false, created_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:32", updated_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:32">, #<Search id: 22, name: "montre", presence: false, created_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:35", updated_at: "2012-03-29 00:45:35">]
```

I want to count the number of occurences of the same elements **based on "name"**. I know how to find the occurences in an array like this one : `['a', 'b', 'a']` with

```
favoris.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
```

But how can use that in the previous array?

Comment: Simple. Replace `h[v]` with `h[v.name]` (or however you get the name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
favoris.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v.name] += 1; h }
```

:)

Comment: I needed to wait 8 minutes before I could.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a solution based on `each`, as you're actually iterating on every element of the array, while producing side effects. That, for how I understand it, is not the reason `inject` was created.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
favoris.each { |el| h[el] += 1 }
```